# Android Relative Layout add Margin when Align Parent

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout in my Android view.

I am trying to get the middle text to have some right padding or margin based on the EDIT icon. See below the image I'm going for.

However I can't seem to get the middle text to perform. It runs all the way up to the EDIT button.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#26265e"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location_white_18dp"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tiLocationAddress"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"

        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to say layout_toRightOf for your text view:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tiLocationAddress"
    //android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" - remove this
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1" - add this
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"

    />
```

Comment: Not sure if @aherrick intend to have the edit button move along with the text, so if the TextView contents change, the Edit widget will be right next to where the TextView ends.

Comment: using toRightOf and toLeftOf got me where I needed to be Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want them to move then use linear layout with weighsum instead of relative.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend forcing the Edit Button or TextView to the End or Right, and then specifying that your other TextView to remain to the left of Edit.
For that you will need to define an ID and reference it, like so:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tiLocationAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="rfnfjeknfwfwe welfmdlwekmklwemfklwemfw welmfweklmflwkmfwl"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnEdit"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:id="@id/btnEdit"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true"

        />
```